# Child Viewmodel in the tab page is not working in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have tabbed pages in my project where I have to bind same few items in all the three tabbed pages.But the viewmodel is not executing in that.

xaml :

```
<TabbedPage.Children>
    <Views:TabPage1>
        <Views:TabPage1.BindingContext>
            <ViewModel:TabPage1VM/>
        </Views:TabPage1.BindingContext>
    </Views:TabPage1>
    <Views:TabPage2>
        <Views:TabPage2.BindingContext>
            <ViewModel:TabPage2VM/>
        </Views:TabPage2.BindingContext>
    </Views:TabPage2>
    <Views:TabPage3>
        <Views:TabPage3.BindingContext>
            <ViewModel:TabPage3VM/>
        </Views:TabPage3.BindingContext>
    </Views:TabPage3>
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

Now each Viewmodel is inheriting the main Viewmodel and in one child ViewModel :

```
RestClient temp = new RestClient();
        var gettempdetails =   temp.Servicetypes();

        if (gettempdetails.status == "success")
        {
            listdetails = new List<ServiceDetail>();
            foreach (Datum2 data in gettempdetails.service_details)
            {
                Datum3 Display = new Datum2();
                Display.name = data.name;
                Display.rate = data.rate;
                Display.time = data.time;
                Display.type = data.type;
                Display.image = "uncheck.png";

            }
```

While debugging, the above code is not executing.
Any Solution?
Also here is the code for RestClient inside the child viewmodel:

```
 public RestClient()
    {
        client = new HttpClient
        {
            MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000
        };
    }


    public async Task<ServiceItem> Servicetypes(int shopid)
    {

        var formcontent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("branch_id",Convert.ToString(shopid)),

        });
        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://saloonbooking.com/index.php/branch/get_single_branch_details/", formcontent);
        var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceItem>(data);
        return status;
```

Comment: Hi Rini, welcome... Can you post the exact error details here?

Comment: I am not getting any error but the RestClient isn't working and while debugging Restclient initialization is done and then goes to the end of the class.

Comment: Where the `RestClient` related code is living? It is unclear why and how it is expected to run.

Comment: Pleas share the code, it is very hard to help without seeing it.

Comment: Code is now  added to the question

Comment: Sorry, from the shared code it is unclear where and how the code is executed. If you want us to help, please show how you execute the code from your ViewModel.

Comment: @RiniAnn - shouldn't you pass `int` param in `temp.Servicetypes();`